# Object showing throught other object in viewport

Tags: objects, 3d-view, geometry

My object is overlapping the other object in the viewport.
The smaller model in the 'back' is showing through the larger model. They both have mirror and subdiv modifiers on them.

Front view
[image: two objects in the viewport the rear one overlapping the other]

Side view to show that the model is behind the larger one.
[image: two objects in the viewport]

Comment: what is overlapping or wrong here? I must be missing something, but when I look at your pictures I dont see the problem.

Comment: Sorry - The smaller modell should be behind the other one - on the image at the top it should be covered by the top geometry - if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck X-Ray in Object->Display

[image]

if not, could you add the blend file, so I can check it?

Comment: That's it!

Thanks a lot - Don't know how I haven't thought about that first..

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I had the same issue where a mesh would appear to be in front of everything in Viewport only.

I found another fix for people with the same problem in Blender 3.5:

1. Select Mesh that is behind and overlapping everything causing problems
2. On the right side go to Properties > Object Properties > Viewport Display
   (Object Properties is the orange square icon)
3. Uncheck "In Front"